# Neo4j Cypher update node dynamic properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Neo4j nodes: `Value`. Each `Value` node can have `0..N` properties in the following format:

```
Value1 node properties:
    property.1 = 123
    property.23 = 1
    property.452 = 5

Value2 node properties:
    property.45 = 90
    property.4 = 7

...

ValueN node properties:
    property.12 = 2
    property.46 = 17
    property.101 = 32
    property.3000 = 84
```

I don't know the certain number of these properties for every `Value` node but during the Cypher query, I need to update all of them.

I need to write Cypher query that will update all `Value` nodes in the database and increment every value of every `Value.property.X` +1.

Please note that the `Value` node can also contains other properties but I only need to update the properties in the mentioned format: `property.X` where `X` can be any number.

Please show how it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
MATCH (n:Node)
UNWIND keys(n) as key
WITH n,key where key contains 'property.'
SET n['key'] = n['key'] + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I apologize, but I forgot to mention that the `Value` node can also contains other properties but I only need to update the properties in the mentioned format: `property.X` where `X` can be any number

Comment: is this still valid in new versions? I am getting syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Trying to dynamically set a property value in Neo4j (i.e., use a variable for the property name) results in an error like
`Invalid input '[': expected ":"`
I imagine this is the syntax error that [@adnanmuttaleb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3579212/adnanmuttaleb) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960114/neo4j-cypher-update-node-dynamic-properties/73830972#comment113731967_49960135), which is described better within the [setProperty](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.setProperty/#usage-apoc.create.setProperty) documentation (see the section on Usage Examples).

Below is the code from [tomaž-bratanič](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6692895/toma%c5%be-bratani%c4%8d)'s [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960135/9312373), modified to use [apoc.create.setProperty](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.setProperty/) instead.

```cypher
MATCH (n:Node)
UNWIND keys(n) as key
WITH n, key WHERE key CONTAINS 'property.'
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(n, key, n[key]+1) YIELD node as N
RETURN properties(N)
```